# Php Curl return 200 but not posting

Tags: php, http, post, curl, request

I'm sorry to disturb you but I can't figure out what is the error on my code. I'm trying to Make a HTTP Post Request on the following , my response code is 200 but It doesn't work. 
Below is my code. If anyone can help I would appreciate his effort very much.

```
    <?php

//create array of data to be posted

$post_data['data[title]'] = 'TITLE';
$post_data['data[category_id]'] = 'Register';
$post_data['data[private_business]'] = 'private';
$post_data['data[description]'] = 'Description for anyone';
$post_data['data[param_size]'] = '1129';
$post_data['data[param_price][currency]'] = 'RON';
//$post_data['data[param_price][0]'] = 'price';
$post_data['data[param_price][1]'] = '100';
//$post_data['data[param_price][2]'] = '';
$post_data['data[param_state]'] = 'used';
$post_data['data[city]'] = '26711';
$post_data['data[person]'] = 'Ion';
$post_data['data[email]'] = 'email';
$post_data['data[accept]'] = 'on';


//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection =
  curl_init('http://olx.ro/i2/adauga-anunt/');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.17 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$headers = array();

//$headers[] = 'Host: olx.ro';
//$headers[] = 'User-Agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0';
//$headers[] = 'Accept: */* ';
//$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';
//$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
//$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
//$headers[] = 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest';
//$headers[] = 'Referer: http://olx.ro/i2/adauga-anunt/';
//$headers[] = 'Content-Length: 594';
//$headers[] = 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=otsg9lalsh5m06faaviuqtmih4; xtvrn=$542850$540516$; optimizelySegments=%7B%221067457090%22%3A%22ff%22%2C%221087063106%22%3A%22none%22%2C%221060248541%22%3A%22direct%22%2C%221042136847%22%3A%22false%22%2C%221092431561%22%3A%22none%22%2C%221079661599%22%3A%22ff%22%2C%221027596252%22%3A%22false%22%2C%221069071887%22%3A%22direct%22%7D; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1425804897718r0.9477511105813824; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; POPUPCHECK=1425891298025; is_tablet=0; __utma=29471969.1470095060.1425804898.1425804898.1425804898.1; __utmb=29471969.61.10.1425804898; __utmc=29471969; __utmz=29471969.1425804898.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); last_used_locations=%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A%224%22%2C%22cityId%22%3A%2226711%22%2C%22districtId%22%3Anull%2C%22label%22%3A%22Brasov%22%2C%22details%22%3A%22Brasov%22%2C%22source%22%3A%22adding%22%2C%22precision%22%3A%22precision-adding%22%7D%5D; mobile2=desktop; ki_t=1425808476633%3B1425808476633%3B1425808476633%3B1%3B1; ki_r=';
//$headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
//$headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
//$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';


//curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);



//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .
                curl_error($curl_connection);

if(curl_errno($c))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($curl_connection);
}

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);
 return $result;
?>
```

The curl informations about errors that I receive are on the following code.

> Array ( [url] => http://olx.ro/i2/adauga-anunt/ [content_type] =>
>   text/html; charset=UTF-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 418
>   [request_size] => 556 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0
>   [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.35955 [namelookup_time] =>
>   0.009494 [connect_time] => 0.160634 [pretransfer_time] => 0.160793 [size_upload] => 302 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0
>   [speed_upload] => 839 [download_content_length] => 0
>   [upload_content_length] => 302 [starttransfer_time] => 0.359489
>   [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] =>
>   178.21.159.40 [primary_port] => 80 [local_ip] => 172.17.64.2 [local_port] => 36961 [redirect_url] => ) 0-

Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the post string correct, you must urlencode it. For example in description string you have spaces which break the post string.

Change

```
$post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
```

to

```
$post_items[] = $key . '=' . urlencode($value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked like a charm. I was spent days trying to make this curl post and finally with your help it worked. Now I must figure a way to upload multiple photo files and set variables to the "values" to use them on html page. Thanks again for your help!!! Really appreciate!

Comment: My command (curl -v -F r=Repo -F e=nupkg -F g=111 -F a=ProjectName -F v=1.0.0 -F p=nupkg -F file=D:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.141.1\_work\1\a\ProjectName.1.0.0.nupkg -u admin:pwd http://hostname:8081/repository/Repo/ ) giving HTTP status code 200 but file is not getting uploaded. Any Idea ?