# Why is PHP cURL PUT request not working despite getting status code 200 in return?

Tags: php, curl, request, put

I've been stuck with this problem for a little while now. I am trying to use a REST API to change certain settings of a user like clear a user and set their device to inactive.

The REST calls are made in php which I am pretty new to. Most calls (get and post) are working just fine so I think I understood the basic concept of php and curl but I just can't get put requests working. The problem is that when making the REST call I get a status code 200 in return indicating that everything went fine but when I check the database nothing changed and the device is still active.

I've spent several hours researching this problem here on stackexchange ([cURL PUT Request Not Working with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947205/curl-put-request-not-working-with-php), [Php Curl return 200 but not posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925567/php-curl-return-200-but-not-posting), [PHP CURL PUT function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585513/php-curl-put-function-not-working)) and additionally reading various tutorials. 
To me my code looks fine and makes perfect sense because it is similar to many examples I found online. So please help me find my mistake.

```
$sn = "123456789";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/api/sn/".$sn);

$data = array("cmd" => "clearUser");
$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$username = 'XXX';
$password = 'XXX';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: if set `Content-Type: application/json` maybe `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as I can see, you have two problems in your code.

1. `Content-Type: application/json` is incorrect, I would remove it entirely.
2. You don't have a `Content-Length` header.

I suggest trying

```
$sn = "123456789";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/api/sn/".$sn);

$data = array("cmd" => "clearUser");
$httpQuery = http_build_query($data);
$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($httpQuery)
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$username = 'XXX';
$password = 'XXX';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$httpQuery);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You define in the Header 'Content-Type: application/json'. Try to encode your $data to json and then transfer the jsonEncodeteData:

```
$dataJson = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataJson);
```

perhaps this helps already.

Answer (score 0):

status 200 may not be a success in the case of a PUT request. In a correct semantics (correct implementation of the server) successful PUT returns "201 Created" and, if the client sends empty or somehow wrong content, the server returns "204 No Content".

Lazy programmers may just return "200 Ok" instead of 204 with the meaning "your request is fine, but there is nothing to do with the data".

Try to verify your data and make sure that you send something that is not empty and is conformal to the API specs.